# jsch connectionerror PortforwardingL at localhost porting

Tags: jdbc, jsch, portforwarding

I having some trouble with establishing a jsch connection.

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:1234 cannot be bound.com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Here is my code:

```
String user = "datafromcli";
        String password = "n5gbz7f";
        String host = "192.168.0.195";    // These are the details of my host/server in order for 
        int port=22;                      // the javaprogram to connect with ssh IP-user
        try
            {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            lport = 1234;                 // This is an outgoing port from my client
            rhost = "192.168.0.195";      // this is yet again the host/server
            rport = 3306;                 // This is the incomming port of my host/server
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.connect();
            int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
            System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
            }
        catch(Exception e){System.err.print(e);}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            go();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
          System.out.println("An example for updating a Row from Mysql Database!");
          Connection con = null;
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";       // (note) 
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + rhost +":" + lport + "/";   // (note2)
          String db = "tradb";                             // the name of the db in mysql
          String dbUser = "test1";         // the user in mysql
          String dbPasswd = "huuge242";  //the pass in mysql
          try{
          Class.forName(driver);
          con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, dbUser, dbPasswd);
          try{
```

(note) I have been trying to find the socalled Driver(both in jsch and jdbc man pages but with no luck, i have thought there might be imformation in the jsch or jdbc .jar files but i haven't decompiled them yet to see.

(note2) Im not sure is the jdbc:mysql:// is a prefix for the adress or a symbol for another url.

I have been opening port 22(for ssh to the server), 1234(for the client) and 3306(mysql for the server) on my router/switch. The server is connected to the client through a 5 port router/switch and usually ssh and ftp works manually, both with filezilla and terminal.

I have made // comments in order to explain how i understood the lines of code. perhaps i interpreted it wrong.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

You have to add boundaddress as 0.0.0.0 , 
Try to modify your code as below and check

```
String boundaddress ="0.0.0.0";
int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(boundaddress,lport, rhost, rport);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the user does not have permissions to bind on the address.